# Best Practice of logging an uncaught exception in a java programm

Tags: java, exception, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Global Exception Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548487/java-global-exception-handler)

I thought of something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    startOfMyProg();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
     log.error(e.toString());
     // Maybe rethrow it so i can see it in the console?
  }
}
```

It's a simple solution, i know. Maybe someone knows a better one?

regards && tia
  noircc

Comment: Well you can get better results buy using just `Exception` or `Throwable`. Some exceptions will get past runtime exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would

```
} catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error("Uncaught exception", e); // prints the stack trace.
```