# Catch exceptions within an entire Java application

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

Is there any method to handle/catch all exceptions thrown by a Java application, without spamming costly `try{}catch(Exception e){}` statements everywhere?

For example, PHP has the function `set_error_handler()`.

**Back story** - Despite tough testing, sometimes bugs can get through, and users are always less than cooperative with helping to fix these.
Ideally, I'd like to hook the application up to a web service facility that can keep track of any stack traces thrown by a user's application.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548487/java-global-exception-handler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` ?