# How to catch ExceptionInInitializerError?

Tags: java, static-initializer

I want to install some kind of global handler to catch any `ExceptionInInitializerError` which could be thrown from any static block when some class is loading. Currently it dumps a stack trace to the stderr and exits the application. I want to log a stack trace using my logging framework, then exit the application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler is what you are looking.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1548497/6529383) will provide you with more information.

In essence you need to install default exception handler as soon as possible:

```
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            if (e instanceof ExceptionInInitializerError) {
                // do something with you're exception
                // and than close application
                System.exit(-1); // passing 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It seems that System.exit isn't necessary, as JVM exits anyway, so I just log exception in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make a global exception handler and just filter your exception out of it.

**Example**

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof ExceptionInInitializerError) {
            //Your handler code
        }
    }
});
```