# What is the best way to throw an Exception but not stop the program?

Tags: java, exception

Please find below an example of my need. Indeed, I don't want to close the entire process because even if it throw an Exception, it can continue.

*Loop*

```
// set a lot of variables and execute some methods
for (int i = 0, i < items.length; i++) {
     // blablabla
     myMethod()
     // blablabla2
}
// some code here also
```

*MyMethod()*

```
// blabla
if (!found)
     throw new EndCurrentProcessException()
// blabla
```

*EndCurrentProcessException*

```
public void EndCurrentProcessException() {
     ??? What I'm supposed to put here to stop the loop iteration ???
}
```

Maybe that used `throw new` is not the good way to do.

I hope it is clear, if it is not, do not hesitate to ask me more informations.

Comment: `Indeed, I don't want to close the entire process` - `What I'm supposed to put here to stop the CURRENT process` So do you want to stop it or not? Its unclear what you're asking

Comment: Do you mean stop executing `MyMethod()`? You could always just `return;`, after of course logging any errors or informing the user of the failure, etc.

Comment: Your exception should describe what the faulty behaviour is, not handle the problem itself. And by process, do you mean iteration in the loop?

Comment: why do you want to throw an Exception in the first place? Exceptions are used for things you don't have influence on (File IO, Network, Hardware etc.).

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by process, because I don't think you're using that terminology correctly. The Java program _is_ a process, so maybe you mean method? Either way, you can write custom exception handlers. How you go about it depends on the application and/or frameworks you're using. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548487/java-global-exception-handler

Comment: Try-catch block

Comment: Thank you all for your comments: Yes by process I mean loop iteration. I cannot used return because here it is a simple example. In the real progam I have 5 o 6 methods which are called and the process could be stopped due to a problem in the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw an exception. Handle the method failure whichever way you see fit.

In your example, modify the **myMethod()** method to return boolean **true** if it was successful and **false** if it was not:

> Loop:

```
// set a lot of variables and execute some methods
for (int i = 0, i < items.length; i++) {
   // blablabla
   if (!myMethod()) {
       // Skip this particular ITEM...
       continue;
       // Or whatever you want.
   }
   // blablabla2
}
```

> MyMethod():

```
public boolean myMethod() {
    // ... Method code ...
    if (!found) {
        return false;
    }
    // ... Possibly more Method code ...
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try-catch statement.

```
for (int i = 0, i < items.length; i++) {
    // blablabla
    try {
        myMethod();
    } catch(EndCurrentProcessException e){
        // do something or continue;
        continue;
    }
    // blablabla2
 }
 // some code here also
```

Comment: is that catching an exception stops the execution in progress?